# Does Django DateTimeField supporting time with time zone information?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

When I post a time with timezone information eg:2013-02-27T14:00:00-05:00 to a Django datetime field throws a form error  "Enter a valid date/time.".

My form field is defined as below

```
 time = forms.DateTimeField()
```

I also tried passing in date formats to the form filed. eg:

```
DATE_FORMATS = [
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%z',
]
time = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=DATE_FORMATS)
```

Does Django DateTimeField not support time with timezone information?

Comment: From the [timezone documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-input-in-forms): *When you enable time zone support, Django interprets datetimes entered in forms in the current time zone and returns aware `datetime` objects in `cleaned_data`.*

Comment: So, no, it doesn't support adding the timezone as part of the entry form.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Django DateTimeField supports timezones, but if you take a look at the documentation, you have to specify it separately from the actual DateTime in your form. Specifically, the documentation recommends that you activate a timezone on a per user basis, otherwise you will always end up entering the DateTime in the default timezone.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-input-in-forms

This is the documentation I used for my project, and it worked out well.

In addition, if you need to specify a specific timezone in a form field, you can always create a drop down field with all of the timezones in it, and then save the DateTime in your view with the correct timezone.